# Calling onActivityResult to determine when a file has been received

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, onactivityresult

I have a `WebActivity` that sets a `JavascriptInterface` for a `WebView`, on the Interface I have created various methods to be called with Javascript for different tasks, one of them is to send a file through Bluetooth. 
The file sends just fine, but I want to inform the user when the file has already been accepted and transmited completely on the other end.

I am trying to use `onActivityResult` on my main WebActivity and also have tried on the separate class that handles the Bluetooth transmission and has a method called on the JavascriptInterface but I am not getting any callback results after the file is succesfully sent:

//First attempt

```
public class WebActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         //some code here
         //Here I set the interface              
          myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data)  {

        if (requestCode == 0) {             

            //This message is shown after the file transfer has started but no 
            //finished
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){                   
                //It doesn't work here either I always get Activity.RESULT_CANCELED (0)
                //flag afer the file transfer has started 
            }

        }

} 


}
```

//Second Attempt

```
public class BluetoothTasks {

//code here 

   private void startTransferIntent() {

    //some more code here

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);       

    intent.setType("text/plain");       

    File file_to_transfer = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +  
    "/txtTransfer.txt");        
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(file_to_transfer));

    //some more code here

    Activity act = (Activity) mContext;
    act.startActivityForResult(intent, TRANSFER_RESULT);      

   }

   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data)  {

        if (requestCode == TRANSFER_RESULT) {
            //Not working here either
            //code that is not executed
        }

   }    

}
```

Could you please tell me if there is a way to do this and if so how would be accomplished?. Thank you.

Comment: What's the intent you're using to transfer the file? Is it `ACTION_SEND`?

Comment: @matiash, please check on the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to accomplish that :/